# ClassNotFoundException after migrating to androidx

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, androidx

I am getting crash in my Google play developer console **after migrating my app to androidx.
The crash is limited to Android pie devices**

Here is the stack trace.
    java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6590)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6115)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6021)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:207)

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1748)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6863)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)

  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:537)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:169)

  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)

  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)

  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider (AppComponentFactory.java:121)

  at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateProvider (CoreComponentFactory.java:62)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:6574)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6115)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6021)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:207)

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1748)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6863)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)

  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:537)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I think it has something to do with

```
  at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateProvider (CoreComponentFactory.java:62)
```

why might be this code in old namespace be called?

I am not able to reproduce the crash locally.

Comment: Try to find something CoreComponentFactor.instantiateProvider in androidx. android.support.v4.app is now old so you should replace it with androidx. Have you tried to let it import automatically from androidx?

Comment: Do you use multidex in your application?

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk yes

Comment: Same problem here. Have you fixed it somehow?